# change string type to date in golang

Tags: go, time

I am getting an input of type string `Wed 2022-08-10 09:08:53 UTC` for a server .I need to check for how long the server is up and running.
I am trying to parse this string to date and then subtract it from current time to get the uptime in minutes.
I am getting error in parsing the string while using `time.Parse()`. I am thinking there is some issue with my layout.

Comment: What is the error? Show the code you have so far

Comment: I am looking for an easy way to update this string to time..So that I can get the difference using time.now(). My understanding of layout might not be very accurate. 
I am  trying with different layouts  
```current := "Wed 2022-08-10 09:08:53 UTC"

 tt, err := time.Parse(time.RFC1123Z, current)
 if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
 } ```
Always get cannot parse error  
`parsing time "Wed 2022-08-10 09:08:53 UTC" as "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700": cannot parse " 2022-08-10 09:08:53 UTC" as ", "`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format seems a bit unique and I could not find predefined constant for it in time package. But you could construct your own format string

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main(){
    t, err := time.Parse("Mon 2006-01-02 15:04:05 MST", "Wed 2022-08-10 09:08:53 UTC")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("time since: %v", time.Since(t))
}
```